# Difference clamp and clip circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, pcb, analog, tvs

What is the difference clamp circuit and clipping circuit? TVS diode clamp property and clamp circuit is same or not? I am confused because of some pictures. Please explain this confusion.

This is TVS diode clamp property.

[image]

This is a clamper circuit

[image]

This is clipper circuit

[image]

What is the clapper meaning? TVS diode clapper and clip circuit is same or not? What is the real difference clamp function between first and second circuit?

Comment: Please explain in depth.

Comment: bb0667 - Hi, Please note the [site rule](/help/referencing) which says that when a post includes content (e.g. text, image, photo etc.) copied or adapted from elsewhere, that content must be correctly referenced. The source webpage or PDF etc. should be linked as a minimum (references for books / articles should include title, author(s), publisher, edition, page numbers etc.). Therefore please can you [edit] your question to include the link(s) for the original source(s) for each of those images. Thanks.

Comment: The first circuit seems to be erroneous: it shows two diodes clamping in the same direction, one to a negative voltage which therefore dominates, and no clamping in the negative direction.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the term "clipper" for a circuit that limits its output at some high or low level or both, but otherwise leaves the output unchanged from the input.

I would use the work "clamp" for a circuit that adds an offset to its output such that the output is never below (or alternatively above) a certain value.

Thus, as I use the terms, your first circuit is a bipolar clipper, not a clamp. It is unfortunate that it is sometimes called a clamp, because that confuses the distinction between clipper and clamp. But I cannot control other people's use of words.

The 2nd and 3rd circuits, I would label as you have done in the question.

The 2nd is a clamp. It shifts the output so that it never negative.

The 3rd is a clipper. It leaves the output un-shifted, but clips off excursions that are above or below certain limits. However, you will sometimes see the diodes in such a circuit referred to as "clamping" diodes. Again, it is confusing, but little can be done to enforce particular usages.

Answer (score 0):

Your first and last circuits are both clippers - they chop off the top and bottom of the input waveform.

A clamp circuit will hold some part of the input waveform at a certain DC level, but keep the full input waveform.

Answer (score 0):

The middle circuit is more likely, or more properly, called a "DC restore" circuit.  At least when the RC time constant is much longer than the period of the signal.